# Allow disabled blocks to be inserted in nested custom blocks

Tags: drupal-8, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to prevent user from insert certain core blocks such as core/paragraph, core/heading, core/list... as root elements (I only want some custom blocks to be at the top). But at the same time, I need to allow it their use in nested custom blocks.

I tried to disable it via Drupal 8 GUI, and js. But it appears to be a global & absolute list of allowed/disallowed Blocks that controls the InnerBlocks appender too.

The js I tried:

```
dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).hideBlockTypes( [
    'core/paragraph',
] );
```

The InnerBlocks that i use inside the custom blocks:

```
      <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={['core/paragraph', 'core/heading', 'core/list']} />
```

Is there a way to do this "Gutenberg friendly"?

I'm using Gutenberg in [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do what you want with a combination of these two modules

https://www.drupal.org/project/bean

https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference

I haven't used gutenberg, sorry.

There's also some useful discussion here around creating a block region in your theme which is always hidden and allocating blocks there so they are enabled (as in, can be queries for) but not rendered.
https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2877132

Comment: They are gutenberg blocks, not drupal blocks. Maybe the tags that i put are confusing...